# How to move from a fragment of a navigation drawer to an Activity on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So, this is my first question here. I am doing a project on Android Studio and I cannot seem to move from a fragment of a navigation drawer activity to one another. I've tried the solutions provided here earlier such as using:-

> Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Main3Activity.class);
>
> startActivity(i);

The intent keeps taking me to MainActivity instead of Main3Activity. Here's my DetectFragment.java code:-

```
public class DetectFragment extends Fragment {

private DetectViewModel detectViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    detectViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DetectViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detect, container, false);
    Button btnOpen = root.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
    });        
    return root;
}
}
```

If anyone has any solution, please do reply. Thanks.

Comment: At first check your `Main3Activity` class. In most cases beginners copy paste implementation and forget to use correct `setContentView()` layout

Comment: Thanks @StanislavBondar, I had copied the code in Main3Activity and hadn't paid attention to the setContentView() layout. You're a lifesaver, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had copied the code in Main3Activity and hadn't paid attention to the setContentView() layout and it was set to MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should start `Main3Activity.class` when pressing `btnOpen`.

I think your problem is that `Main3Activity.class` is crashing and being instantly destroyed.

See `LogCat`

Comment: I found the problem. I had copied the code in Main3Activity and hadn't paid attention to the setContentView() layout and it was set to MainActivity. However, thanks for replying.